# limiting the echo variable from database

Tags: php

i got a question, if i show my variable and the value of variable is from database, like this :

`<?php echo $name ?>`

so i want to echo or show my variable, but i want just the first 6 character of `$name` is show but the rest is not showing. and the question is how to limiting the value of variable when the value of variable is from database

if the value of `$name = 'ebcdefghij';`so variable will be show just 'abcdef'

is that posible to limiting the value of variable?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a part of a string you can use substr:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
In your case it would be:

```
echo substr($name, 0,6);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
echo substr($name, 0, 6);
```